# $\DeclareMathOperator\isZero{isZero}$ Proving $isZero(x) = 1 - \frac {x^2 + 1 - (|x + 1|) (|x - 1|)}{2}$ for $x < 0$ and $ x > 0$ (x is an Integer)

Tags: absolute-value

not been on here in a while, but in this case I'm working on a blog article regarding an $\mathrm{isZero}$ function, which returns $1$ for true (the input is zero), and $0$ for false (the input is not zero). The function is based on taking advantage of the fact that:

$$\mathrm{isZero}(x) = 1 - \frac {x^2 + 1 - (|x + 1|) (|x - 1|)}{2}$$

I can programmatically test this for all values of $x$ *(ADDENDUM: in the integer space)*, I've run all sorts of tests in Excel, JavaScript and other programming languages. I can prove it algebraically quite easily for $0$, just substitute $x = 0$ and everything reduces down perfectly to give me the $1$ that confirms the is-zero case.

However, *(ADDENDUM: in the case of an integer x)*, where $x > 0$ or $x < 0$, when I pull graphs for $y = |x - 1|$ for $x > 0$ or $y = |x + 1|$ for $x < 0$, I find myself face to face with the inflection point where $x = 1$ for the former graph and where $x = -1$ for the latter graph, and I'm not sure how I could reduce down the $\mathrm{isZero}$ function equation based on whether I'm dealing with a positive non-zero value of $x$, or a negative non-zero value of $x$. I was wondering if anyone would know how I can prove in both cases that a non-zero value of $x$ yields a zero as a result of the above equation, thus satisfying the equation?

EDIT: I remembered that I was originally working with x being only in the integers space, thanks to 5xum. Apologies to all for having forgotten about this. I will update the main question accordingly with the necessary addenda.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your equations.

Comment: So $\,\operatorname{isZero}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) \ne 0\,$?

Comment: Is $x$ an integer value or float?

Comment: Why use an expression to test for zero? Why not simple code "if (var==0....)"

Comment: Apologies to all, x is indeed an integer... I had forgotten that my original testing of this function was based solely on integers.

Comment: @NoChance, this function comes from a programming language subset that has a limited set of functions, no if-then-else clauses, and statements are branchless and thus require a branchless (i.e. mathematical) approach to change specific values based on other variables. In this programming language, min() and max() are available as well as basic mathematical operators, so it's been a little tricky to work with to derive new functions based on what little ones I have available to me.

Comment: I see, I thought that a zero test would be fundamental language capability, but I am no PL Design expert. Thanks for your explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To really analyze the value of your expression, first off, you can simplify the expression a bit to only have one absolute value. Since $|a||b|=|ab|$ and $(x+1)(x-1)=x^2-1$, you can simplify your expression into

$$1-\frac{x^2+1-|x^2-1|}{2}$$

Now, you you need to split cases, but not into $x<0$ and $x>0$! You need to split the cases into regions where the values under the absolute sign are always positive or negative!

In your case, $x^2-1$ is **positive** if $|x|>1$, and **negative** if $|x|<1$. So let's split cases.

1. If $|x|\geq 1$, then
   $$\begin{align}
   1-\frac{x^2+1-|x^2-1|}{2} &= 1-\frac{x^2+1-(x^2-1)}{2}\\
   &= 1-\frac{x^2+1-x^2+1}{2}\\
   &= 1-\frac{2}{2}\\
   &= 0
   \end{align}$$
   so your hypothesis is correct, the expression does evaluate to $0$.
2. If $|x|< 1$, however, then
   $$\begin{align}
   1-\frac{x^2+1-|x^2-1|}{2} &= 1-\frac{x^2+1-(-(x^2-1))}{2}\\
   &= 1-\frac{x^2+1+x^2-1}{2}\\
   &= 1-\frac{2x^2}{2}\\
   &= 1 - x^2
   \end{align}$$
   so in this case, the expression is not equal to $0$.

In fact, your expression could most compactly be written as $\max\{0, 1-x^2\}$, or if you want the most explicit version, I would write it as

$$\begin{cases}1-x^2&\text{ if }-1\leq x\leq 1\\
0&\text{ otherwise}\end{cases}.$$

---

Note, importantly, that so long as you evaluate the function on **integer** values, the function is indeed equal to $1$ for $x=0$, and it is also equal to $0$ for **all other integers**! This is because $0$ is the only integer that satisfies the equation $|x|<1$ and thus the only one that falls into the first case of the above analysis.

Comment: The second case should probably be $|x| \ge 1$.

Comment: @MartinR Yes, of course, thanks for catching that one.

Comment: @5xum, of course! I had been dealing with integers in my use cases all those years back when I started working on this problem, the focus had been only on integers, which probably explained why I was having a mental block about everything in between. Thank you for pointing it out, and especially with consolidating the |a||b| component of the equation.

Comment: @Martin R Shouldn't it be the other way around?

Comment: Note that it is even simpler if you write it as ${\rm isZero}(x) = \frac{{1 - x^2  + \left| {1 - x^2 } \right|}}{2}$. Also, in general, $\max (a,b) = \frac{{a + b + \left| {a - b} \right|}}{2}$.